# Using apply in R with an additional vector argument

Tags: r, vector, matrix, apply

I have a matrix of size 10000 x 100 and a vector of length 100. I'd like to apply a custom function, *percentile*, which takes in a vector argument and a scalar argument, to each column of the matrix such that on iteration *j*, the arguments used with *percentile* are column *j* of the matrix and entry *j* of the vector. Is there a way to use one of the *apply* functions to do this?

Here's my code. It runs, but doesn't return the correct result.

```
percentile <- function(x, v){
  length(x[x <= v]) / length(x)
}

X <- matrix(runif(10000 * 100), nrow = 10000, ncol = 100)
y <- runif(100)
result <- apply(X, 2, percentile, v = y)
```

The workaround that I've been using has been to just append *y* to *X*, and re-write the percentile function, as shown below.

```
X <- rbind(X, y)
percentile2 <- function(x){
  v <- x[length(x)]
  x <- x[-length(x)]
  length(x[x <= v]) / length(x)
}
result <- apply(X, 2, percentile2)
```

This code does return the correct result, but I would prefer something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand that `R` is vectorised and know the right functions you can avoid loops entirely, and do the whole thing in one relatively simple line...

```
 colSums(  t( t( X ) <= y ) ) / nrow( X )
```

Through vectorisation R will recycle each element in `y` across each column of `X` (by default it will do this across the rows, so we use the transpose function `t` to turn the columns to rows, apply the logical comparison `<=` and then transpose back again.

Since `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively we can use `colSums` to effectively get the number of rows in each column which met the condition and then divde *each column* by the total number of rows (remember the recycling rule!). It is the exact same result....

```
res1 <- apply(X2, 2, percentile2)
res2 <- colSums(  t( t( X ) <= y ) ) / nrow( X )
identical( res1 , res2 )
[1] TRUE
```

Obviously as this doesn't use any R loops it's a *lot* quicker (~10 times on this small matrix).

Even better would be to use `rowMeans` like this (***thanks to @flodel***):

```
     rowMeans(  t(X) <= y  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest and clearest way is to use a `for` loop:

```
result2 <- numeric(ncol(X))
for (i in seq_len(ncol(X))) {
  result2[i] <- sum(X[,i] <= y[i])
}
result2 <- result2 / nrow(X)
```

the fastest and shortest solution I can think of is:

```
result1 <- rowSums(t(X) <= y) / nrow(X)
```

SimonO101 has an explanation in his answer how this works. As I said, it is fast. However, the disadvantage is that it is less clear what exactly is calculated here, although you could solve this by placing this piece of code in a well-named function.

flodel also suggester a solution using `mapply` which is an `apply` that can work on multiple vectors. However, for that to work you first need to put each of your columns or your matrix in a `list` or `data.frame`:

```
result3 <- mapply(percentile, as.data.frame(X), y)
```

Speed wise (see below for some benchmarking) the for-loop doesn't do that bad and it's faster than using `apply` (in this case at least). The trick with `rowSums` and vector recycling is faster, over 10 times as fast as the solution using `apply`.

```
> X <- matrix(rnorm(10000 * 100), nrow = 10000, ncol = 100)
> y <- runif(100)
> 
> system.time({result1 <- rowSums(t(X) <= y) / nrow(X)})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.020   0.000   0.018 
> 
> system.time({
+   X2 <- rbind(X, y)
+   percentile2 <- function(x){
+     v <- x[length(x)]
+     x <- x[-length(x)]
+     length(x[x <= v]) / length(x)
+   }
+   result <- apply(X2, 2, percentile2)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.252   0.000   0.249 
> 
> 
> system.time({
+   result2 <- numeric(ncol(X))
+   for (i in seq_len(ncol(X))) {
+     result2[i] <- sum(X[,i] <= y[i])
+   }
+   result2 <- result2 / nrow(X)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.000   0.024 
>
> system.time({
+   result3 <- mapply(percentile, as.data.frame(X), y)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.076   0.000   0.073 
>
> all(result2 == result1)
[1] TRUE
> all(result2 == result)
[1] TRUE
> all(result3 == result)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 I didn't see you had the `rowSums` answer in amongst all that other stuff. I think you should highlight that more because it's a good answer. I'm leaving my answer up because I have explained how it works.

Comment: @SimonO101 I edited my answer. I hope it now stands out more. I also referred to your answer for an explanation.